# Python Pandas : dataframe groupby and aggregation UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: unicode, pandas

i have a dataframe y that i read it from a csv file with has two columns one for text and other for votes

```
>>> y = pd.read_csv("./path/to/my/doc.csv",encoding="utf-8")
>>> y
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 43977 entries, 2 to 72308
Data columns:
vote    43977  non-null values
text    43977  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
```

what i need to is group by unique text and omit remove controversy text which has mixed votes, (only keep text groups which all of them has same vote  either 1 or -1 )
there's no nans in the data so far.
the "text" column values are in arabic utf-8 read characters

what i have tried is :

```
g = y.groupby("text")  #grouping by unique text 

#is the set of the group has more than 1 unique value return 0 
#otherwise return real value (which also = to max) 
g.agg({"vote": lambda x : 0 if len(list(set(x))) > 1 else x.max()}
```

unfortunately i have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/frame.py", line 454, in __repr__
    self.info(buf=buf, verbose=self._verbose_info)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1077, in info
    print >> buf, self.index.summary()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/index.py", line 118, in summary
    index_summary = ', %s to %s' % (str(self[0]), str(self[-1]))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y['text_as_str'] = y.text.astype(str)
g = y.groupby('text_as_str')
g.agg({"vote": lambda x : 0 if len(list(set(x))) > 1 else x.max()}
```

Comment: the first line give me the same UnicodeEncodeError, probably also it wasn't clear (edited now ) that i read the data using pandas.read_csv function which AFAIK fills the datatypes automatically in the dataframe